# Segmentation fault while referencing and adding values to a structure

Tags: c

Okay, so the problem concerns adding values through function to structure. Honestly, I couldn't solve the problem (spent a lot of time trying), so I am asking for your help. While executing the program, I get a `segmentation fault`. It occurs while using the variables from `stack stos`.

```
typedef struct e {
    int zaglebienie[100];
    char *nazwa_funkcji[100];
    int poz;
} *stack;

void put_on_fun_stack(int par_level, char *funame, stack stos) {
    int i = stos->poz;
    stos->zaglebienie[i] = par_level;
    char *funkcja = strdup(funame);
    stos->nazwa_funkcji[i] = funkcja;
    stos->poz++;
}

int main() {
    char *p = "makro";
    stack stos;
    stos->zaglebienie[0] = 0;
    put_on_fun_stack(1, p, stos);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `poz` in uninitialized.

Comment: **Never ever* `typedef` pointers! You eventually run into trouble sooner or later. In your case it was sooner.

Comment: Translation to the above: `stos` is an non-allocated pointer. Yes, the typedefed pointer have confused me too.

Comment: @Olaf what do you mean exactly? Same problem occures while typedefing ...}stack and changing all the "->" to ".". I dont really get the point of your answers.

Comment: It's not the "same problem" for sure. Right now you are dereferencing some uninitialized and unallocated pointer.

Comment: The details are explained in your C book. As @EugeneSh. wrote, it can hardly be "the same problem". Not all problems are "the same", `1 != 2`.

Comment: [try this](http://ideone.com/sUvigP)

Comment: typedef struct e{
    
  int zaglebienie[100];
        char *nazwa_funkcji[100];
        int poz;
    
 
    }stack;



    void put_on_fun_stack( int par_level, char *funame, stack stos ) 
    {
        int i=stos.poz;
        stos.zaglebienie[i]=par_level;
        char * funkcja = strdup(funame);
        stos.nazwa_funkcji[i]=funkcja;
        stos.poz++;
    }

    int main(){
 char *p="makro";
 stack stos;
 put_on_fun_stack(1, p, stos);
 return 0;
    }

So here's "another" problem, but still with segmentation fault. Sorry for the format.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a pointer to `stack` but you're not allocating any memory to it.

And as already mentioned in the comments, using `typedef` with with a pointer will unnecessarily complicate your life.

So I suggest you create the `struct stack` and then in main declare a pointer to `stack` and allocate memory for it, somewhat like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct e {

    int zaglebienie[100];
    char *nazwa_funkcji[100];
    int poz;

} stack;


void put_on_fun_stack(int par_level, char *funame, stack *stos)
{
    int i = stos->poz;
    stos->zaglebienie[i] = par_level;
    char *funkcja = strdup(funame);
    stos->nazwa_funkcji[i] = funkcja;
    stos->poz++;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *p = "makro";

    // calloc to initialize stos variables to 0
    stack *stos = calloc(sizeof(stack), 1);

    printf("stos->poz before: %d\n", stos->poz);
    put_on_fun_stack(1, p, stos);
    printf("stos->poz after: %d\n", stos->poz);
    printf("stos->nazwa_funkcji[0]: %s\n", stos->nazwa_funkcji[0]);


    free(stos->nazwa_funkcji[0]);
    free(stos);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
stos->poz before: 0
stos->poz after: 1
stos->nazwa_funkcji[0]: makro
```

Comment: Thats pretty the thing i wanted to do, but still ive got error : 3[Error] invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'stack* {aka e*}' [-fpermissive] in Dev-C++ or Initializer element is not constant in VIM

Comment: I've answered in C (because of the C tag in your question). In C++ you have to explicitly cast the return value of `malloc` & co to the type you want. So try `stack *stos = (stack*) calloc(sizeof(stack), 1);`

Comment: I meant ive used C++ compiler from Dev and C compiler from VIM (gcc/cc command)

Comment: Still, there is an error "initializer element is not constant
 stack stos = (stack) calloc(sizeof(stack), 1);
 ^
Btw. Im using pointer to a structure and cant change it, cause thats the part of project.

Comment: Actually did all the changes, that u suggested and still have got segmentation fault.

Comment: The code I've posted doesn't cause a seg fault (you can see it here: http://ideone.com/7WSG30). But if my answer doesn't fit your needs, you can try @BLUEPIXY 's solution if you want to go with something different: http://ideone.com/sUvigP

Comment: @chrislacorunna: you did not make the changes suggested by yLaguardia. You must change your typedef to `typedef struct e stack;`.  It is bad style to hide pointers behind typedefs, it is error prone and leads to confusing code for both the programmer and the reader.